# Como o Ruby gerencia as dependências de uma aplicação?

Tags: ruby

Eu gostaria de saber como o Ruby gerencia as suas dependências? Ele faz algo semelhante ao *node* que instala todas dependências dentro de um diretório (*node_modules*) na raiz do projeto ou é possivel criar um ambiente virtual como no *Python* e instalar as dependências dentro dele?

Comment: Pesquise por RubyGems.... talvez seja isso que vc esteja se referindo.

Comment: Mais ou menos. Minha duvida esta relacionado com o RubyGems so que eu estou mais interessado em: onde ele baixar as dependencias e como e resolve os conflitos de versao entre dependencias de aplicacoes distintas. Eu vou editar a minha pergunta, acho que ela nao foi muito precisa.

Comment: @DaniloMartodeCarvalhoCarva, não cometa tantos esses de português quando estiver a perguntar: isso demonstra preguiça e falta de cuidado e pode desanimar alguém a te responder.

Answer (score -2):

As dependências são instaladas num diretório compartilhado, onde todas as aplicações usando a mesma versão Ruby usarão a mesma dependência. Se duas aplicações usarem a mesma versão Ruby, mas versões diferentes da dependência, será instalado ambas as versões da dependência em diretórios separados. A estrutura desse diretório também depende de qual gestor de ambiente estás a usar: *rvm*, *rbenv* etc.

Entretanto, é possível instalar as dependências no mesmo diretório do projeto, configurando o *path* do *Bundler*.

Comment: Você tem que usar um bundler.

Comment: @AugustoVasques, a pergunta foi sobre os diretórios; é óbvio que tem que usar o Bundler, mas a pergunta não foi "o que usar para gerenciar versões", mas como o Bundler gerencia os repositórios.